# How to share Cloud Endpoints module with two Android Studio Projects

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an Android Studio Project with my App and a Cloud Endpoints Module. My App is able to successfully access my Endpoints modules classes and everything works well.

Now I want to build a totally new Android Studio App but I want to use that same Cloud Endpoints API. What is the best way to do that exactly? Can I "Share" that Endpoints module from my first project? Or do I somehow have to generate some JARS or something and paste those into my second project?

Maybe go to File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> App -> Dependencies and then add the file structure from the Android Studio Project Endpoints folder?

EDIT: Also, how do I specify/manage imports of the google JARS? Everything was auto generated for me when I made my first project so I am kind of lost as to how to do it myself from scratch. -noobie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your projects are on the same machine, you can include the path to the appengine project in your settings.gradle file for your new Android project (instead of allowing the system to use conventions to determine it).  This mechanism will keep all the *magical* build mechanisms intact.

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':backend'
project(':backend').projectDir = new File('path/to/project')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did and it worked:

On the project tab I expanded "External Libraries" and then found my endpoints library. It has the name `<your-endpoints-module-name>.android-endpoints`. Expand that one more time and you will see `<your-endpoints-module-name>.android-endpoints.jar`. Right click on that and go to "Show in Explorer". This is the Jar for your endpoints class. Just copy paste it into the `libs` folder in your second project and run sync gradle files.

Now in your second project you are going to have to add some dependencies.Go to `File -> Project Structure -> app -> Dependencies` and click the plus sign and then select `Library Dependency`. Then search for `com.google.api-client:google-api-client`. This will give you a bunch of results. Add these two to your project and click OK:

`com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0`

`com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0`

Not sure if both of those are needed but that is what I did to make it work.

Now every time I update my endpoints module in Project 1, I'll just have to copy/paste that updated .jar file into Project 2.